# Convert one JSON format to another

Tags: javascript, json, oracle-jet

I want to convert one below json format to respective json format. The Json I receive from Rest services is not supporting the design.I tired to implement the below list view

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=listView&demo=jsonHierListView

JSON Format (I receive from Rest services)

```
{
  "ActionHistory": [{
      "id": "action",
      "name": "Action History",
      "children": [{
        "childrenItem": {
          "id": "action1",
          "type": "fa fa-info",
          "empId": "101",
          "ActionDate": "on 18-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
          "Action": "Submit",
          "From": "Deb Raphaely",
          "To": "Neena Kochlar",
          "pic": "deb_avatar",
          "Details": ""
        }
      }, {
        "childrenItem": {
          "id": "action2",
          "type": "fa fa-info",
          "empId": "101",
          "ActionDate": "on 19-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
          "Action": "Approve",
          "From": "Neena Kochlar",
          "To": "James",
          "pic": "neena_avatar",
          "Details": ""
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": "action",
      "name": "Action History2",
      "children": [{
        "childrenItem": {
          "id": "action1",
          "type": "fa fa-info",
          "empId": "101",
          "ActionDate": "on 18-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
          "Action": "Submit",
          "From": "Deb Raphaely",
          "To": "Neena Kochlar",
          "pic": "deb_avatar",
          "Details": ""
        }
      }, {
        "childrenItem": {
          "id": "action2",
          "type": "fa fa-info",
          "empId": "101",
          "ActionDate": "on 19-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
          "Action": "Approve",
          "From": "Neena Kochlar",
          "To": "James",
          "pic": "neena_avatar",
          "Details": ""
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON format I need

```
{
  "ActionHistory": [

    {
      "attr": {
        "id": "action",
        "name": "Action History"
      },
      "children": [{
          "attr": {
            "id": "action1",
            "type": "fa fa-info",
            "empId": "101",
            "ActionDate": "on 18-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
            "Action": "Submit",
            "From": "Deb Raphaely",
            "To": "Neena Kochlar",
            "pic": "deb_avatar",
            "Details": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "id": "action2",
            "type": "fa fa-info",
            "empId": "101",
            "ActionDate": "on 19-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
            "Action": "Approve",
            "From": "Neena Kochlar",
            "To": "James",
            "pic": "neena_avatar",
            "Details": ""
          }
        }

      ]
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "action",
        "name": "Action History"
      },
      "children": [{
          "attr": {
            "id": "action1",
            "type": "fa fa-info",
            "empId": "101",
            "ActionDate": "on 18-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
            "Action": "Submit",
            "From": "Deb Raphaely",
            "To": "Neena Kochlar",
            "pic": "deb_avatar",
            "Details": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "id": "action2",
            "type": "fa fa-info",
            "empId": "101",
            "ActionDate": "on 19-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
            "Action": "Approve",
            "From": "Neena Kochlar",
            "To": "James",
            "pic": "neena_avatar",
            "Details": ""
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tired to convert the JSON format and it worked well for JSON array of length=1.For greater Array length it is not working.
Here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/72mz5zft/

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think essentially what you're trying to do is pretty simple mapping:

```js
var person={"ActionHistory":[
  {
    "id": "action",
    "name": "Action History",
    "children": [
      {"childrenItem": {
        "id": "action1",
        "type": "fa fa-info",
        "empId": "101",
        "ActionDate": "on 18-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
        "Action": "Submit",
        "From": "Deb Raphaely",
        "To":"Neena Kochlar",
        "pic":"deb_avatar",
        "Details":""
      }
      },{"childrenItem": {  
        "id": "action2",
        "type": "fa fa-info",
        "empId": "101",
        "ActionDate": "on 19-Apr-2017 18:20:32",
        "Action": "Approve",
        "From": "Neena Kochlar",
        "To":"James",
        "pic":"neena_avatar",
        "Details":""
      }
        },
      {"childrenItem": {  
        "id": "action2",
        "type": "fa fa-info",
        "empId": "101",
        "ActionDate": "",
        "Action": "Pending",
        "From": "James",
        "To":"",
        "pic":"james_avatar",
        "Details":""
      }
      }
    ]
  }
]};

var result = {
    ActionHistory: person.ActionHistory.map(function(item){
        return {attr: {
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
            children: item.children.map(function(child){
                return {
                    attr: child.childrenItem
                }
            })
        }}
    })
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Jamiec.It worked well.
Thank you for you quick response